# signal switch (control rod) replacement in 1990 Volvo 240 DL

Tags: volvo

Will a signal switch without cruise control work on a 1990 Volvo 240 DL?

I have a bad turn signal switch on my Volvo. It's the left-hand rod that you use to control the turn signals, brights, and cruise control. It's having both mechanical and electrical failures and needs to be replaced.

However, this part is hard to find and very expensive. On ebay it's going for $500 to $700.

I've also found a switch for a 1990 Volvo 240 without cruise control for about $50.
Will those switches fit and work in my Volvo -- albeit sacrificing cruise control?

Or is that cheaper switch somehow just totally incompatible?

Comment: I would expect you don't need to replace the whole stick.
There is a good chance someone who is a skilled autoelectrician or someone who works with automotive electronics could repair it for you. They may also be able to take the required switch gear from a cheaper non-cruise control stick and transplant it into the cruise-control enabled stick allowing you to keep cruise-control and replace the worn parts.

Comment: @H.Daun Good idea. Thanks. I might be able transplant the wiring harness for the cruise control if it's a separate connector as you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the functions are compatible except you loose the cruise.

Check the pin outs of the connectors as the functions are linked to the wire colors... you might find that the cruise switch has 3 connectors to the two for the other switch.

If the switch can be fitted, you may even be able to add an extra switch or switches to keep cruise once you work out what the control is.

I had a 240 estate and sourced many parts from scrap yards - full electric locking, full electric windows etc so checking the wiring is a must.

Comment: Thank you. (Lacking in reputation, I can't upvote.) This is exactly the sanity check I was hoping for. I'll definitely check the wiring before buying the non-cruise stick.